# How can i Query two where statements in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

What i trying to do is to query two where statements in firestore using the ionic and angular framework but the thing is i know how to do a single where statement but not two. So how can achieve the this.

The code i used to get one where query is this:

```
getgame(id)
{
  return this.afs.collection<review>('games', ref => 
  ref.where(
      'Euserid', '==', id
  )).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data();
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { id, ...data };
  })))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just add another `.where`

```
getgame(id) {
  const ref = this.afs.collection<review>('games');

  return
    ref
      .where('Euserid', '==', id)
      .where('x' , '==','y'))
    .snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data();
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { id, ...data };
  })))
}
```

Or something similar.

Checkout: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries